# Rails conditional validation if radio button value is "some_string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, radio-button

I would like to validate the field `marketing_source_other` if the value of the radio `marketing_source` is set to `other`.

If a user selects other from the `marketing_source` field, it will bring up an text input for the user to put in how they find out site.

How can I do validations in rails such that:

```
  validates_presence_of :marketing_source_other :if [marketing_source == "other"]
```

What should the `:if` part be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  validates_presence_of :marketing_source_other, :if => lambda {|obj| obj.marketing_source == "other"}
```

Comment: I will mark this as correct when I the time limit allows me to